# How can I add new data to CollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is my code

`var attendees: [Attendee]`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return attendees.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"Cell", for: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

    let attendee = attendees[indexPath.row]

    let name = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    name.text = attendee.fullName

    let degree = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    degree.text = attendee.attendeeDegree

    let address = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    address.text = attendee.address

    let address1 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    address1.text = attendee.address2

}`
```

And I have:
    `var results = [Meetings]()`
this "results" have like "attendee" address, full name and address2. So my question is how can I add this data to my collection view? I need add `results.fullName` to `name.text = attendee.fullName`

I tried to do it in other way but doesn't`succeed((

Answer (score 2):

You have an array `attendees` that serves as your data model. Just append new items to your array and then call reloadData() on your collection view. It will call the data source methods and redraw itself with the new data.

There are other methods that let you only redraw the newly added items, but the above is simple and will work.

Comment: Ok, so why won't my solution work? How are you passing your results from CoreData to your collection view?